# Open a popup window on top of a popup window in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, popup, window.open

I have a scenario where I have a popup window open and that will have links to open up another window that's going to pop open on top of the already open popup window. I've tried all sort of tricks (javascript window.open, target="_blank" etc.) but nothing seem to work. It always was opening the page on the already opened popup window.

Any suggestions? Appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

You realize that what you're doing with popups is going to be considered by many users a form of spam right?

But to answer: I believe _resource will open them separately.

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean but it's a user requirement and don't have an alternative.